# Postman Status: 401 Unauthorised - Using Postman as a client for java application that connects to SQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, postman

I'm using springboot to build a java application written in IntelliJ IDEA community edition that connects to an SQL database.

I want to use Postman as a client to submit requests (such as Post and Get) and check whether my code is working.

In my application.properties, I have written the connection details to my database:

```
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/person
    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = secret
    server.port = 8080
```

In my DB Browser, I have added the MySQL database and can connect to it.

In my controller, I have written

```
    @RequestMapping("api/v1/person")
```

and in postman, I have put the request URL as localhost:8080/api/v1/person

If I try a POST request, I get status 401 unauthorised.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The 401 Error is not related to the Database, it is related to the REST-call itself. What kind of authentication method do you use in Postman and Spring?

Comment: I currently am not using any authentication method.  For Authorization method, I have specified 'No Auth' in Postman.  Do I need to specify authorization because my SQL database has a password?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your postman's header section that are you passing any Authoriation related key and value pair. Check also in hidden headers.

Comment: I am using KEY: Content-Type and VALUE:application/json

Comment: Have you added any security configuration to your app